# How to read Directional Key Press and Do something in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, move

i am trying to learn android app development.
i want to move an object using up,down,right,left arrow key.
please anyone helps me on how to read the pressed directional key and move the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)
    {
        //your code
 return false;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
    {
          /*yourcode*/                                          

return false;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT)
    {
        //your code                                         
return false;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT)
    {
        //your code                                         
return false;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)
    {
        //your code                                         
return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Edited code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
    {
        Toast.makeText(<Activity_name>.this, "Application Quits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          finish();
          return false;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: i tried your method, but when i run the app, the program crash everytime

Comment: please if you give me a sample of full code implementing only one key, it will be great help.

Comment: use this method outside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

override the onkeydown function and compare the keycode with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN etccccc

Comment: thanks, but if you give me an sample code example it will be more easier for me to understand.